# WP API get user data

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I'm authenticating users iva JWT Auth on WP Rest API from a React Native app, so, something like that:

```
export function userAuth(username, password) {
    return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestLogin());
    const appAuth = new FormData();
    appAuth.append('username', username);
    appAuth.append('password', password);

    return fetch(wp.jwtEndpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: appAuth
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function(body) {
          if(body.token){

            getUserDataFromUsername(body.user_nicename, body.token, dispatch);
            return dispatch(userSuccessLogin(body));
          }
          else {
            return dispatch(userFailLogin(body));
          }         
        });
  }
}
```

The response for this request is:

```
{ token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKXXXQ',
      user_email: 'supertest@gmail.com',
      user_nicename: 'super-test-avatar',
      user_display_name: 'TEST TEST' }
```

My issue is: as I can't get user ID from there, how can I retrieve user data form a request like `https://www.wp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/${userId}`?

*I tried using https://github.com/dest81/wp-api-get-user-by-username, which would allow me to do that based on username, but its endpoints goes to 404, so I think it's outdated.*

Comment: i do it with this another rest api there just need post bearer+jwt to this url https://www.wp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me

Comment: I am having the similar issue. Is there any update on this?

Comment: I have the same problem, I need to get the user ID. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I ended up making a custom API endpoint. More doc about that : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/